# awk to improve command print Match and Non-Match case:

Tags: awk

Would like to read and compare first field from two files then print

1. Match Lines from Both the files - ( Available in f11.txt and f22.txt)       -> Op_Match.txt
2. Non- Match Lines from f11.txt   ( Available in f11.txt Not-Available in f22.txt)-> Op_NonMatch_f11.txt
3. Non- Match Lines from f22.txt   ( Available in f22.txt Not-Available in f11.txt)-> Op_NonMatch_f22.txt

Using below 3 separate commands to achieve the above scenario's .

f11.txt

```
10,03-APR-14,abc
20,02-JUL-13,def
10,19-FEB-14,abc
20,02-AUG-13,def
10,22-JAN-07,abc
10,29-JUN-07,abc
40,11-SEP-13,ghi
```

f22.txt

```
50,DL,3000~4332,ABC~XYZ
10,DL,5000~2503,ABC~XYZ
30,AL,2000~2800,DEF~PQZ
```

To Match Lines from Both the files:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} ($1 in a) {print $0,a[$1]}'   f22.txt f11.txt> Op_Match.txt

10,03-APR-14,abc,10,DL,5000~2503,ABC~XYZ
10,19-FEB-14,abc,10,DL,5000~2503,ABC~XYZ
10,22-JAN-07,abc,10,DL,5000~2503,ABC~XYZ
10,29-JUN-07,abc,10,DL,5000~2503,ABC~XYZ
```

To Non- Match Lines from f11.txt:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} !($1 in a) {print $0}'   f22.txt f11.txt > Op_NonMatch_f11.txt

20,02-JUL-13,def
20,02-AUG-13,def
40,11-SEP-13,ghi
```

To Non- Match Lines from f22.txt:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} !($1 in a) {print $0}'   f11.txt f22.txt > Op_NonMatch_f22.txt

50,DL,3000~4332,ABC~XYZ
30,AL,2000~2800,DEF~PQZ
```

Using above 3 separate commands to achieve the mentioned scenario’s. Is there any simplest way to avoid 3 different commands?  Any Suggestions ...!!!

Comment: try comm http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucomm.htm

Comment: comm doesn't work on fields within lines, just whole lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, untested:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    fname1 = FILENAME
    keys[NR] = $1
    recs[NR] = $0
    key2nrs[$1] = ($1 in key2nrs ? key2nrs[$1] RS : "") NR
    next
}
{
    if ($1 in key2nrs) {
        split (key2nrs[$1],nrs,RS)
        for (i=1; i in nrs; i++) {
            print recs[nrs[i]], $0 > "Op_Match.txt"
        }
        matched[$1]
    }
    else {
        print > ("Op_NonMatch_" FILENAME ".txt")
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i in recs; i++) {
        if (! (keys[i] in matched) ) {
            print recs[i] > ("Op_NonMatch_" fname1 ".txt")
        }
    }
}
' f11.txt f22.txt
```

The main difference between this and Kent and Etans answers is that theirs assume that the $1 in f22.txt can only appear once within that file while the above would work if, say, `10` occurred as the first field on multiple lines of f22.txt.

The other difference is that the above will output lines in the same order that they occurred in the input files while the other answers will output some of them in random order based on how they're stored internally in a hash table.

Comment: I had that question mark (if F22 can have dup lines) in mind too until I saw OP's codes

Comment: It just never occurred to me until I saw your answer that there might NOT be duplicate key values in f22.txt.

Comment: I'm with Kent. I just assumed the OP got the conditions right.

Comment: You might be right. Often the scripts posted by the OPs are wrong but idk if that's the case or not here.

Comment: Ed Morton: Wow, It’s Rocks, It is working the way expected, Thanks a ton for good support !!!

Answer (score 0):

here is one:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}
    $1 in a{print $0,a[$1]>("common.txt");c[$1];next} 
    {print $0>("NonMatchFromFile1.txt")}                     
    END{for(x in a)
        if(!(x in c)) 
            print a[x]>("NonMatchFromFile2.txt")}' f2 f1
```

with this, you will get 3 files: `common.txt, nonmatchfromFile1.txt and nonMatchfromfile2.txt`

Comment: I think your population of `c[$1]` is in the wrong place. You don't need the parens around the strings that represent the output files - you only need the parens when you're constructing the file names there, e.g. by concatenation.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, you are right, came from a bad edit, I fix it irght now

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked @EdMorton's answer but he will quite likely have gotten it right.

My solution (which looks slightly less generic than his at first glance) is:

```
awk -F, '
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$0;
    next
}
($1 in a){
    print $0,a[$1] > "Op_Match.txt"
    am[$1]++
}
!($1 in a) {
    print $0 > "Op_NonMatch_f11.txt"
}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        if (!(i in am)) {
            print a[i] > "Op_NonMatch_f22.txt"
        }
    }
}
' f22.txt f11.txt
```

Comment: If the OP can't have dup key values in f22 and doesn't care about the order of the lines output in the END section then yours and Kents solution would work fine.